# @Html.Raw in MVC 4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

i was trying to create a news website which display its content from several news websites

as start am trying Webclient little bit and working fine on a simple  Web Form

but when get to MVC i get: The name 'read' does not exist in the current context

CODE BELOW:

```
public ActionResult News() 
    {
        var read = "";
        var msg = "";
        try
        {
            WebClient myC = new WebClient();
            read = myC.DownloadString("http://localhost:61123/Videos");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and the News.cshtml view:

```
@ViewBag.Message.msg
@Html.Raw(read)
```

any tips .. even if i should try something else to get specific content from other websites ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` is a local scoped to the controller action method.  The view doesn't know about it.  You have to explicitly send it to the View.  You can do this with ViewBag.

```
try
{
    WebClient myC = new WebClient();
    read = myC.DownloadString("http://localhost:61123/Videos");
    ViewBag.Read = read;
}
```

and then in your view

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Read)
```

You can also create a Model class and strongly type the view to your model, or even a List of instances of your Model class

Comment: Nailed it from the very first time Thanks ;)
BTW if you got my point is WebClient the ideal solution for that task
and how to determine which HTML tags to view
i.e: not to include page menus , logo  ..etc

Comment: You'd be much better off getting an RSS feed to do this, which all major news providers should have.  If you absolutely must parse HTML, try HTML Agility Pack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/